# Install CURRENT version of Gradle within CI

Tags: bash, gradle

Gradle describes their installation in their docs:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html

However the docs requires using specific version and there is no easy way to say "get the current version".

I would like to do something like:

```sh
export GRADLE_VERSION=`curl https://services.gradle.org/current-version`
curl -sSLO https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && unzip -q -d /opt/gradle gradle-*.zip \
    && echo "PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}/bin" > ~/.bashrc
```

Obviously there is no such API service like `/current-version`. How would you achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
curl -s 'https://services.gradle.org/versions/current' | jq -r '.version'
```

Output:

```
7.3.1
```

or

```
curl -s 'https://services.gradle.org/versions/current' | jq -r '.downloadUrl'
```

Output:

```
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.1-bin.zip
```